# Call Amazon Lambda from Extendscript (Or get a http invoke url for Amazon Lambda)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, extendscript

I am trying to call my Amazon Lambda from an extendscript script for After effects, but I can't find a way to get a http (extendscript has no https support) invoke url for the Lambda. Here is the code that I am currently using :

```
if (conn.open ("<myAPI>.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:80")) { // I need the http url here
    conn.write ("GET /version1 HTTP/1.0\n\n");
    reply = conn.read(512);
    conn.close();
}
```

Currently the only invoke url I can find is https://api.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Is there a way to get a http address instead ? Or to make the https one work with extendscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I route the http trafic to the https Gateway using an Amazon CloudFront.

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway **does not support** `http`, only `https`. From [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/):

> Yes, all of the APIs created with Amazon API Gateway expose HTTPS endpoints only. **Amazon API Gateway does not support unencrypted (HTTP) endpoints.**